# What sharing with Science Fiction & Fantasy should be done?

Tags: discussion

When people ask questions about the TV show aspects of Dr. Who (specific scenes and such) or when someone asks a question about Game of Thrones (while only wanting knowledge in how it relates to the show, not the SoIaF series) over on the Science Fiction & Fantasy StackExchange, should they be directed here?

Likewise, with people asking questions that relate to the book version of a Science Fiction or Fantasy movie or TV show, should we direct them over to Sci Fi & Fantasy SE?

This question spawns from this question:

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10972/who-is-the-lord-of-the-rings/10973

Somebody asking "Who is the Lord of the Rings?", a question that is best answered relative to book knowledge.

Comment: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/376/how-do-you-distinguish-when-a-question-should-be-asked-at-se-movies-vs-se-scifi

Comment: FWIW, I think the question you refer to is poor and easily answered elsewhere. That said I don't think it should be closed just on the grounds that its probably better answered on sci-fi.

Comment: @iandotkelly I can't believe I missed that, thank you very much for linkage

Comment: Oh, and I wasn't saying "let's close this blasphemer's question RIGHT NOW!" I was just curious for my own education, and what I should be doing in the future.

Comment: Hi. No problem missing the old question, and yes, I know you we're not saying 'close now' but as a mod I feel that I have to explain my actions and the question has attracted some close votes. It will probably be closed without me casting a mod supervote, on the grounds it is trivia rather than scifi I think.

Comment: @iandotkelly I completely understand that idea; it felt rather like a buffer question, someone asking that already knew the answer. either way, thanks for the information. And the proof that I wasn't the only one concerned about that.

Comment: From **[Respect the community – your own, and others’](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)** — *"**Be a bit jealous of your site** — Don’t blithely turn askers away simply because their question could be asked somewhere else."*

Comment: My main issue with that question is that the opening narration of the first film answers it.  This is *really basic* stuff that's addressed in the first 5 minutes of the film.

Comment: And honestly, that question wouldn't fare much better on scifi.SE.

Comment: @Keen I think the OP already knew the answer, just wanted to ask a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the actual question, unless there is a VERY, VERY strong reason for a question to be migrated, the question should stay on the site it was asked on unless migration is asked for by the user.

Some examples of when to migrate questions to another site:

- non-scifi movie question on scifi
- non-movie scifi question on movies and tv

I don't include scifi movie questions that rely on a lot of details in the answer coming from the books/other sources because we have quite a bit of that going on already, especially with LotR questions.